# network folder share issue in Windows

Tags: windows-xp, security, windows-server-2008

I am using Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I want to share a disk folder and I want users to be able to access directly (e.g. using `\\10.10.10.123\shared` in Windows resource explorer) without using user name and password. Guest account does not work for me since it needs user name (Guest). Any solutions?

BTW: the same solution for Windows XP is also ok.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried disabling 'Password Protected Sharing' in the Network and Sharing Centre?

Comment: In the "Network and Sharing Centre", I did not see an option called 'Password Protected Sharing'. Do you mean Windows Server 2008 or Windows XP?

Comment: Just a thought, if you're running a Domain this won't work, otherwise http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753176%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: I am not in active directory domain. Any ideas what is wrong? BTW: I have found 'Password Protected Sharing' is disabled. from the link you provided, I did not find how to disable username and password.

Comment: To achieve your requirement, use 'Public Folders' shared to the 'Everyone' group. Once password protected sharing is disabled, you will not need a user name or password to connect.

Comment: Hi Pulse, for example on machine 10.10.10.123, I shared a public folder, how could other people access public folder from an UNC path?

Comment: When you share the folder, you provide a name, for example 'documents'. So in explorer you simply type \\10.10.10.123\documents There should be nothing else needed.

Comment: "When you share the folder, you provide a name, for example 'documents'" -- could you advise me how to share a public folder to be some names please (e.g. share public folder as the name "document")? Are there any document? Sorry I did not use public folder before.

Comment: Another question is whether I need to be in Active Directory or Windows domain in order to use public folder?

Comment: You don't need a domain for this to work, being in a 'Workgroup' is fine. To set-up the share, open 'My Computer'. expand 'Libraries' and then which ever of the four sub-folders you desire, for example, 'documents' right click on 'Public documents' and select 'Properties\sharing\Advanced Sharing' make sure 'Share this folder' is selected then enter a name, Select 'Permissions' and add who ever you wish. That should be it. Here's a good read http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_Windows_Server_2008_File_Sharing